# preg_match_all \r\n confusion

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match-all

I try to extract all not formatted urls from a bbcode text.
Regex should match:

```
1. "^http://xyz.abc$"
2. "(http://xyz.abc)"
3. " http://xyz.abc "
```

but not formatted bbcode urls like [url]http://xyz.abc[/url]

The final regex is

```
#(?:^|\s|\()((?:www\.|https?:(?:\/\/)).*?\..*?)(?:\s|\)|$)#i
```

While testing I had some trouble with this and found out the trouble comes from \r\n.
Example:

```
$text = "http://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/1.html
http://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/2.html
http://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/3.html";
//or with \n
//$text = "http://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/1.html\nhttp://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/2.html\nhttp://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/3.html";

preg_match_all('#(?:^|\s|\()((?:www\.|https?:(?:\/\/)).*?\..*?)(?:\s|\)|$)#i', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

$matches contains the first and the last url.

But With \r\n

```
$text = "http://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/1.html\r\nhttp://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/2.html\r\nhttp://www.url.com/xxx/yyy/3.html";
```

$matches contains all urls. Why doesn't it work with \n?

You can verify this here http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html

Comment: so you have trouble with `\r\n` ?

Comment: the problem is that the regex doesn't match the second url if the input comes with \n only

Comment: what do you mean? the extracted url are processed and converted to working bbcode urls like [url=http://...]Title[/url] and placed in the text. so yes, the newlines are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now for myself

```
#(?:^|\s|\()((?:www\.|https?:(?:\/\/)).*?\..*?)(?:\s|\)|$)#im
```

The "m" modifier fixed the ^...$ problem.